# Проблема при выводе ipconfig в файл через cmd

Tags: cmd, кодировка

Я хочу вывести содержимое ipconfig в файл. Я сделал так: открыл cmd.exe и выполнил ipconfig > ip.txt , файл создается, но в файл заносят какие-то кракозябры. Но когда я заношу в файл не ipconfig, а systeminfo(systeminfo > sys.txt) у меня проблем не бывает, все заносится как нужно. В чем может быть проблема?
P.S в консоли всё выводится как нужно. Вывод на русском

Answer (score 1):

Если лень заморачиваться с написанием batch-файла и нет необходимости в выяснении точного имени сетевого интерфейса, то можно выполнить команду в кодировке unicode. Тогда названия переменных станут куда "читабельнее". Хотя кодировка текстового файла получится в ANSI:

```
chcp.com 65001>nil&ipconfig>ip.txt
```

А можно воспользоваться другой командой:

```
wmic nicconfig where (IPenabled ="TRUE") get caption,ipaddress,macaddress>ip.txt
```